# Mega: direct download link for shared file

Tags: dropbox, mega

With Dropbox you can create a link that starts a download directly when opened in a browser. So if you receive an e-mail with a link in the body, clicking the link starts the download directly, without having to open a page which shows a download button.

**Is it possible to create such a link for [Mega](https://mega.co.nz/) as well?**

Comment: MEGA seems to require you to use their add-on for access, which is why the link takes you to a page with a down-load button which then invokes the add-on. Without debugging the add-on and probably invalidating your terms of service, you will probably have to accept that the answer is "no". But I shall be interested if someone else has a different answer.

Comment: Yes there is, though browser downloader speed is fairly high enough. http://onhax.net/mega-idm-download-method/

Comment: I'm currently investigating this question too, there may be a part of a positive answer here : https://github.com/odwyersoftware/mega.py/blob/c27d8379e48af23072c46350396ae75f84ec1e30/src/mega/mega.py#L685

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, no.

Unless you use a third-party tool that bypasses the countdown clock, you are not presented with a direct download link.

If you are paid subscriber to DropBox, I have read that the daily limit for bandwidth is 250GB. That would be very difficult to exceed unless you are sharing pirated movies with strangers. You might want to check with DropBox on what the daily limit for free accounts are though... It might be much less such as 10GB.

Comment: Torrent is not same as direct file downloading though.

Comment: Yes, when you're downloading a 42GB full Blue-ray movie, which is only found on torrents, doesn't have speed cap like direct links.

Comment: The comment has nothing to do with the question or my answer

Comment: "countdown clock" which one? Can I post other awnser with a proper response? i.e.: isn't possible by design (different from Dropbox MEGA files are encrypted and an direct download will only give you garbage unless you handle decryption by yourself).